# Count the number of characters without len() and combine the variables

Tags: python

## Q1

Write code that combines the following variables so that the sentence “You are doing a great job, keep it up!” is assigned to the variable message. Do not edit the values assigned to a, b, c, or d.

## Q2

Count the number of characters in string str1. Do not use len(). Save the number in variable numbs

I've tried some solutions as below. I wonder if there any faster way to solve it?

## Q1

```
a = "You are"
b = "doing a great "
c = "job"
d = "keep it up!"


seq1 = [a, b]
seq2 = " ".join(seq1+[c])
message = ",".join(seq2 + [d])
```

Is there any more simple way to deal with the problem?
I hope I'm not hardcoding lol.

## Q2

```
str1 = "I like nonsense, it wakes up the brain cells. Fantasy is a necessary ingredient in living."

list1 = list(str1)
print(list1)
numbs = count(list1)

print(numbs)
```

Should I use the count function like this in the code? Are there any modules or functions that I could apply? like loop function or Counter function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q1 could also be solved using [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/): `message = f"{a} {b}{c}, {d}"` (requires python >= 3.6). otherwise:  `message = "{} {}{}, {}".format(a, b,c, d)`.

Comment: Where is the count function you're using in part 2?

Comment: Technically `len` and `__len__` are different, so you could do `numbs = str1.__len__()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1 there are various *string formatting* styles. The most recent (python 3.6) is

```
result = f'{a} {b}, {c} {d}'
```

For length, strings are iterable in python, so

```
length = 0
for character in string:
   length += 1
```

or a list comprehension

```
length = sum(1 for char in string)
```

Comment: I've got another question. I'm going to calculate the sum of an iterable list from 0 to 40/ so I type sum1 = sum(1 for num in numbers). But it turns out 40 instead of 820. What's the problem?

Comment: write just `sum(iterable)`. my example counts `1` for each item (since you wanted lenght)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,c in enumerate( yoursting ):
    pass

print(i+1)
```

should do the trick. it will increase the countervariable i each iteration, so fianlly it will be at the length of your string. since it starts at 0 you need to add 1 in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can add strings together in python so you could just add them

```
a+' '+b+c+' '+d
```

I added the ' 's in there because the strings in the variables didn't have them but if they do you can just take those out.
for the second question you could use a loop to count them

```
counter=0
for i in str1:
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: You can use string format function. It uses placeholders and variables.

```
'{0} {1} {2}, {3}'.format(a,b,c,d)
```

Q2: You can iterate each element of the string and increment a counter. This is not the best way but is one of them.

```
a = 0
[a+=1 for _ in str1]
```

Comment: Code-only answers will not support the learning process of the question author which is part of the mission of SO. It would be appreciated if you would add an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

```
by = "You are"
az = "doing a great "
io = "job"
qy = "keep it up!"
message = by+" "+az+io+", "+qy
print(message)
```

**Q2**

```
str1 = "I like nonsense, it wakes up the brain cells. Fantasy is a necessary ingredient in living."
numbs=0
for i in str1:
    numbs+=1
print(numbs)
```